# Substitute for QHttp in Qt 5.2

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtnetwork, qthttp

I wathed a video on youtube about QtNetwork. My Qt version is 5.2.  Qt cannot find the QHttp header. I searched my Mac for QHttp and got nothing. What is the substitute for QHttp in Qt 5.2? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is in a [separate module](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qthttp/source/36f370ac28c5864da5bc1cbd61980e053c1cb4c9%3a) now, so you can use it from there. You would write something like this in your qmake project file:

```
QT += http
```

Please consider using `QNetworkAccessManager` as much as possible, however. QtFtp and QtHttp are there just for aiding the move, but people would need to use them as a last resort.

The reason is that no one maintains them actively and their solution for the use case is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

QHttp has been [made private](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html#changes-to-qt-network), and QNetworkAccessManager should be used instead.

Comment: Note that there are separate add-ons.